# Invalid input syntax for type double precision with POST request to Maps API

Tags: carto

I'm just trying to replicate [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/jorgeas80/4c7169c9b6356858f3cc) but using a different account (libregis), using a raster table called *foto_pnoa*, created just dropping a tif file when creating a new dataset. And I'm getting this error

`{"errors":["Postgis Plugin: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: \"76.4293851819992
 ,10\"\nCONTEXT:  SQL function \"_raster_constraint_info_scale\" statement 1\n\nin executeQuery Full sql
  was: 'select r.r_table_schema sch, r.r_table_name tab, r.r_raster_column col, greatest(abs(r.scale_x
 ), abs(r.scale_y)) scl from raster_overviews o, raster_columns r where o.r_table_schema = 'public' and
  o.r_table_name = 'foto_pnoa' and o.r_raster_column = 'the_raster_webmercator' and r.r_table_schema 
 = o.o_table_schema and r.r_table_name = o.o_table_name and r.r_raster_column = o.o_raster_column ORDER
  BY scl ASC'\n  encountered during parsing of layer 'layer0' in Layer"]}`

when sending a POST request to http://libregis.cartodb.com/api/v1/map, using this as POST body (map config)

`{"version":"1.3.1","layers":[{"type":"cartodb","options":{"sql":"select * from foto_pnoa","cartocss"
:"#foto_pnoa {raster-opacity: 0.5;}","cartocss_version":"2.3.0","geom_column":"the_raster_webmercator"
,"geom_type":"raster"}}]}`

Comment: If the POST is JSON, why does the only double precision value have a terminal semicolon?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. The query that causes the error is an internal one. Not anything I'm sending. I think it may be a bug, or wrong configuration data, on my side.

Comment: Looks like a PostGIS Raster error: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3360

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by [a bug in PostGIS Raster](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3360). It's fixed and working now.